# How to enable udev package in yocto recipe for initramfs build

Tags: linux, yocto, udev, initrd

How to enable udev package in yocto recipe for initramfs build?

Please provide sample yocto bb file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add the following macro in yocto bb file.

IMAGE_INSTALL = "udev"

Comment: I realize this is 2 years old, but if you're running `bitbake <initramfs image name>`, the above is correct.  However if you're configuring an initramfs (name set by `INITRAMFS_IMAGE`) to then hand-off to your runtime image, you want to use `PACKAGE_INSTALL`.  It's a separate list of packages to include in the initrd vs. the main image so that the size remains small.

Comment: What's the difference between `IMAGE_INSTALL = "udev"` and `DEPENDS += "udev"`?